# How do we cause Orchard to render a Taxonomy Link's Menu text?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a taxonomy named My Taxonomy with four terms: TermA, TermB, TermC, TermD. I also have a navigation menu into which I added this taxonomy as a link.

Here are the relevant Edit Taxonomy Link values:

- **Taxonomy** My Taxonomy
- **Root Term** Parent Taxonomy
- **Display top level menu item** false (or true - neither works)
- **Levels to display** 0
- **Menu text** My Taxonomy <----- *(this is what Orchard isn't rendering)*

**What I want** on the front end:

- My Taxonomy

  - TermA
  - TermB
  - TermC
  - TermD

**What I get** on the front end:

- TermA
- TermB
- TermC
- TermD

How do we cause Orchard to render a Taxonomy Links Menu text?

**Edit:**

This is my current kludge in pseudo code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < childMenuItems.Count; ++i)
{
    var childMenuItem = childMenuItems[i];
    if (childMenuItem.Content is TermPart)
    {
        // render the taxonomy terms
        var taxonomyName = childMenuItem.Content.Container.TaxonomyPart.Name;
        var termMenuItems = (childMenuItems as ICollection<dynamic>).Where(c =>
            c.Content is TermPart &&
            c.Content.Container.TaxonomyPart.Name.Equals(taxonomyName));
        i += termMenuItems.Count();

        // rest omitted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you missed this checkbox: [] Display top level menu item. You'll need a root term to contain the others. If you don't like that solution, just add a static menuitem with the name of your taxonomy and put your taxonomy menu items under it.

Comment: Did not know that. Then what is the setting "Menu Text" for?